# Add role in jhipster used keycloak

Tags: oauth-2.0, jhipster, spring-security-acl

I  used  in  my  application  oauth2  with  the server  keycloak,  so  i  want 
 know  how can I add role .i folowed multi-tutoriel but it's not worked .

The  file  that  I  modified  to  add  the  role:

- AuthoritiesConstants.java
- authorities.csv
- users.csv
- users_authorities.csv
- jhipster-realm.json
- jhipster-users-0.json

RQ: the role is added in the database.

thanks.

Comment: Did you found a solution?